# Can I install MS Exchange Server on Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I want to develop an Outlook we add-in. When I try to run something copied from [the MS tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio), I am prompted to "Connect to Exchange email account".

I am guess that this means MS Exchange Server.

Which I don't have.

So, I figure that I will purchase that, or download from MS if it is free; but, when I Google, I only see stuff about installing it on Windows Server.

Can I install MS Exchange Server on Windows 10, which is all that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install MS Exchange Server on Windows 10, which is all that I
>   have?

MS Exchange Server cannot be installed on Windows 10.

> This topic provides the steps for installing the necessary Windows
>   Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, and Windows Server 2016 operating
>   system prerequisites for the Exchange 2016 Mailbox and Edge Transport
>   server roles.

Only the Exchange 2016 management tools can be installed on Windows 10.

> [image]
>   It also provides the prerequisites required to install the Exchange
>   2016 management tools on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 client computers.

## Sources

- [Exchange 2016 system requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/aa996719(v=exchg.160).aspx)
- [Exchange 2016 prerequisites](http://[https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb691354(v=exchg.160).aspx][1])

Comment: There are email service providers that will allow you to purchase an exchange account.  I will not make a recommendation on which services you should look at.